# How to write a script with javascript which fills in then submits a prompt?

Tags: javascript, node.js, automation, ui-automation, prompt

I am trying to write a script (using node.js) which I can use as a task runner or test automation script. I have a web application which uses socket.io where a user can communicate with the server. The application is basically chat application where multiple users can communicate with the server and each other. What I'm trying to do with the script is:

1. Open the URL (done)
2. Wait for page to load (done)
3. Fill in Prompt which will be a username then submit
4. Then repeat 1-3 as another user

The application itself works but I am just in the process of creating scripts which will allow some form of automation testing to observe changes in the css.

So I have the prompt within index.html in a  element:

```
username = prompt("What is your username?");
```

and this is the test script within server.js (a node.js server):

```
ar open = require('open');

console.log('Test script starting...');

open("http://localhost:8080");

console.log('Waiting for DOM to be loaded...');

setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('DOM loaded!');
    //Fill in prompt and submit prompt

}, 5000);
```

Is it possible to fill in a prompt then submit using a script and what language or framework is better for this purpose?

Comment: Is this a nodejs problem?  Or a browser Javascript problem?  There is no DOM in nodejs and there is no `prompt()` function in nodejs.  Very confused about what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am actually unsure of what language or framework is most suitable for writing test automation scripts for javascript/nodejs applications. I have edited the question to make it more comprehensive.

Comment: Use protractor or some other testing framework.  Don't try to write your own.